# duplicate rownames error using rbind and reading the same csv file twice

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames that are identical in length and number of columns. I want to do a simple `rbind`, but get the error

```
> outputdf<-rbind(outputdf,currentcol)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: non-unique values when setting 'row.names':
```

I received help before and build two dataframes by reading the same csv twice for to get different parts of information. I am using these two data frames to build multiple data frames. However, I encounter the duplicate rownames error when using rbind. I have already tried `row.names=FALSE` when reading the csvs and also using `rownames(dataframe)<-NULL` to refresh. I even tried to redo the rownames so that

```
rownames(dataframe2) <- c(nrow(dataframe1)+1):c(nrow(dataframe1)+nrow(dataframe2))
```

which gives me a range that starts after the previous dataframe to avoid duplicate row names.

All of this has failed. I was wondering if i was missing something.

Here is the code, where A is a csv file that i converted from an excel sheet

the file looks like

```
country     USA      Britain
state       NV       
product     peas       corn
   .
   .
source      cnn       fox news

jan-02       3           5   
feb-02       3           2
 .
 .
```

which i had earlier help to convert it into this format

```
country state product units time    ....  source
USA      NV     peas   3     Jan-02        cnn
USA      NV     peas   3     feb-02        cnn
Britain         corn   5     jan-02       fox news
Britain         corn   2     feb-02       fox news
```

the code is

```
        A<-filenames[1]

        #get data as separate df
        datacols <- read.csv(A, header = FALSE, skip = 11, strip.white = TRUE,row.names=NULL)[-c(2:4)]

        #get names as separate df
        names <- read.csv(A, header = FALSE, nrows = 11, strip.white = TRUE,row.names=NULL,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[-c(1:4)]
        datanames<-c(1:11);datanames<-cbind(datanames,names)


        #convertedfile dataset
        outputdf<-data.frame()

        #addtime into dataframe
        timeframe<-datacols[1];colnames(timeframe)<-"time"

        for(colindex in 2:c(ncol(datacols))){

          currentcol<-timeframe


          #bind price col to the current dataframe
          price<-datacols[colindex];colnames(price)<-"Price"
          currentcol$Price<-price

          #add the country
          currentcol$Country<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][1])

          #add market location
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][2])
          currentcol$Market_Location<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add market name
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][3])
          currentcol$Market<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add market latitude
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][4])
          currentcol$Market_Latitude<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add market longitude
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][5])
          currentcol$Market_Longitude<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add commodity
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][6])
          currentcol$Commodity<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add produit agricoles
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][7])
          currentcol$produit_agricoles<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add price type
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][8])
          currentcol$Price.Type<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add unit
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][9])
          currentcol$Unit<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add currency
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][10])
          currentcol$Currency<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #add source
          check<-as.character(datanames[[colindex]][11])
          currentcol$Datasource<-ifelse(nchar(check)<1,"na",check)

          #bind dataframe

          outputdf<-rbind(outputdf,currentcol[1,])
```

Comment: Can you give a more specific data example, e.g a subset of your raw data so that people can know what's really going on? Use `dput` to get the reproducible example.

Comment: When you are sampling these two dataframes from original data, is there any overlap of rows you are sampling in the two new dataframes?

Comment: because both dataframes have the same number of columns as they were obtained from one csv, i ran a for loop for the length of the columns. In df1, each column is unit country data. in df2 each column is the country name and other attributes matching df1 country data. Each column combined from both df1 and df2 becomes a new dataframe. I would like to rbind these new dataframes, but I get the row.names duplicate error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, The dataframes i was trying to merge contained lists inside them, thats why i got the duplicate rowname error. I found this out when i wrote a test csv of a dataframe and saw how messed up it was. I used cbind of the columns instead of doing dataframe$newvariable<-data to create the dataframes